# How to move changes without committing?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, diff, binaryfiles

I'm working on my **laptop** on a source-controlled project, but now I want to move my work to my **desktop**. The thing is, I can't commit because the changes are still **work-in-progress**.

- A solution may be to *Export*, but as far as I know that doesn't take
  into account **file deletion** (which I did).
- Another solution would be to make a patch and apply on the desktop, but the last time I tested, it didn't take into account **binary files** (which I have created and modified).

I don't have admin privileges, so I can't create a new **branch**.

Any other solution / workaround? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just copy the whole working copy including the hidden .svn folder over to your desktop computer.
Zipping first is allowed as well.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a straightforward file-sync problem.  Why not use something like rsync?

```
rsync -a --delete --exclude .git laptop:~/path/to/wd/ desktop:~/path/to/wd/
```

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to sometimes work on your laptop, and sometimes on your dektop, or simply if your changes last more than a day, you should probably create a feature branch and commit there. Once your feature is complete, reintegrate the feature branch into the trunk.

The [SVN book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.branchmerge.commonpatterns.feature) covers feature branches.